# javascript to retrieve post information in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have an input `product` that outputs a codeigniter function result to input `price`.

current syntax (below) fails with error:
`$("#price").value is not a function`

My view javascript function sytax is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#product").change(function () {
    //get the value of the select when it changes
    var value = $("#product").val()

    //make an ajax request posting it to your controller
    $.post('sales/get_sku_prices', {data:value},function(result) {
      //change the input price with the returned value
      $('#price').value(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

`Price` is the targeted input where I want the javascript result to be displayed.

help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$("#price").value` is not a function.

`value` is a property of the DOM node corresponding to an input element. The corresponding jQuery method is called `val`. You have this line inside the `post` success callback:

```
$("#price").value(result);
```

change that to:

```
$("#price").val(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. This works perfect. my issue now is that the contents pushed into the 'price' is an entire html page rather than just the result. any ideas?

Comment: @JustStarting `result` is what the server returns and what you feed to be displayed. Maybe you only want the server to return _only_ what should appear in the `input`? An alternative would be to search the response for the data you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the val() method in order to populate the return value.

```
$('#price').val(result);
```

The value atribute is usually being used as:

```
.attr('value')
```

Comment: Most often you are interested in the `value` _property_ (which can be retrieved via `.val()`), not _attribute_ (which is a different thing).

Answer (score -1):

Try-

```
$.post('sales/get_sku_prices', {data:value},success: function(result) {
```

hope it helps!!

Comment: This won't work. You are not inside an object literal. You are passing an argument. If you want to suggest the object literal syntax, do it properly. I don't think it could cause any error, though.